# Mongo db shell variable printing only once

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

```
> var x = db.sampleDB.find();
> x
```

output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55d02ed690ddbaafbfe20898"), "name" : "aditya", "city" : "meerut" }
```

But if I print this variable again, it does not printing anything.
and I am not able to print `x.name`?

using ubuntu 14.04(db version v2.6.10)

Answer (score 11):

The result returned from `.find()` is a ["cursor"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/) and not a value. So when you do something like:

```js
> var x  = db.sampleDB.find();
> x
```

Then all you are doing is iterating the cursor just as if you did:

```js
> db.sampleDB.find();
```

If you wanted to "keep" the content, then call `.toArray()`

```js
> var x  = db.sampleDB.find().toArray();
> x
```

Or if the result is singular, then just call `.findOne()`

```js
> var x  = db.sampleDB.findOne();
> x
```

These have now all been "converted" from a cursor, which only retrieves results once, in to variable that already has the fetched results.

Comment: This article shows some more options for working with cursors in the shell: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/